# Creating a function that has all columns of a data frame as input in r

Tags: r, function

I have two data frames; ***"clinical"*** and ***"expression"***:
The *"clinical"* dataframe contains data about various clinical parameter (columns) in patients with breast cancer (rows). The *"expression"* contains data about expression gene levels (columns) in patients with breast cancer (rows). The columns name in the *"expression"* dataframe are various ***"gene.ID"***.
Both dataframes have the same patients (rows), and only differ from each other in the columns. However, the rows in each dataframe are not exactly at the same order as the other dataframe.
I want to test and plot the correlation between the expression level of a certain gene and the clinical parameter of the individuals in the cohort.
In order to do so, I am trying to create a function that (1) will receive these dataframes and the gene.ID of a specific gene, (2) extract the expression pattern of this gene, (3) match the patients from both dataframes, (4) go over all the clinical parameters, (5) and do some computations, each time on another clinical parameter.
My main issue is the *"go over all the clinical parameters"* part, although I'm pretty sure the rest of my code is not much better.
So far, my code looks something like this:

```
my_function <- function(clinical_data, expression_data, gene.ID){
  gene.ID <- (expression_data$gene.ID)      
  expression.pattern <- as.numeric(expression$gene.ID)
  matched.samples <- match(row.names(clinical), row.names(expression))
  for(i in names(clinical)){
  ***here will come an if statement***
```

I also think I have a serious problem with the "gene.ID".
I would like to know what I should change in my function so that it will do the job once I write the if statement.
I hope my question is clear enough.

Comment: Have a look at `merge(clinical, expression, by=gene.ID, all=F)`.

Answer (score 0):

> Both dataframes have the same patients (rows), and only differ from
>   each other in the columns. However, the rows in each dataframe are not
>   exactly at the same order as the other dataframe.

The function `cbind` lets you join ("bind") two datasets by columns ("c"). Because each dataset has the same patients, but in a different order, you would need to first sort the rows of one dataset to match the other dataset.

```
cbind(clinical_data, expression_data[rownames(clinical_data), ])
```

Now you just have one `data.frame` that contains everything needed for the rest of the analysis.